# why divider in big calendar component not working

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

as you can see in the picture divider between two first day of work not working , can any body help ma solve problem ?
[image]

and its code is :

```
 <BigCalendar
        // views={['month','agenda']}
        rtl={true}
        events={events}
        startAccessor="start"
        endAccessor="end"
        style={{ height: 500 }}
    />
```

Comment: Is your screen zoomed? If you inspect those elements, are there borders being applied? It might help if you'd grab the compiled HTML and post it along with the CSS file.

Comment: no, its not zoomed . I am not changing anything , I just install the component and use it

Comment: If you set `rtl` to false does the problem persist?

Comment: yes, first I change its value to false and second time hide it but not change anything

Comment: Well, none of the demos I've looked at show the problem. You'll need to do as I ask or we can't really help.

Comment: I see the inspect , the problem is .rbc-day-bg + .rbc-day-bg {
    border-left: 1px solid #DDD;
} not applied for first column and when i add this style , it removes automatically